# Unity3D: How to "chain" animations without resetting?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I imported a cube mesh that contains four smaller sub-cubes. 
The mesh also contains an animation that pushes the smaller cubes out of the big one. When this is done, one of the small cubes "splits" again (it's not really splitting - it just pushes four children out again).

[image: Mesh in hierarchy]

I'd like to trigger these animations when the user clicks on the big cube.The animation was initially exported as one clip but I cut it in half so that I can either trigger the first or the second split.

[image: animation split in two parts]

I attached a Box Collider to the big cube to be able to get an OnMouseDown event and from there I pass an int parameter to my AnimationController that starts the appropriate animation:

```
public class ClickToAnimate : MonoBehaviour {
    private Animator _animator;
    private int _clicks = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        _animator.SetInteger("Clicks", _clicks);
        if (_clicks == 3)
        {
            _clicks = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            _clicks++;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The state switching works fine but when I transition from FirstSplit to SecondSplit, the first animation is reverted so that the four medium cubes are driven back in the big cube before the second animation is played.

I tried enabling "Apply Root Motion" but that doesn't help (probably because the big cube is never actually moving?). So how can I "chain" these animations without resetting them in each step? Are my general ideas regarding the AnimationController and animation splitting correct to handle this and what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried Blend Tree?

Comment: I re-exported the meshes separately with one animation on the BIG cube and another one on the MEDIUM cube. This way, both meshes can have separate AnimationControllers and there are no side effects / dependencies when triggering the animations. I'll look into the blend tree solution though.